# How to provide UA attributes for Image::Grab?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I try to add some UA attributes while using [Image::Grab](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Grab), like:

```
my $fp = 'sha256$26328...';
my $pic = Image::Grab->new( ua => { ssl_opts => { SSL_fingerprint => $fp } } );
```

I tried also as:

```
$pic->ua->ssl_opts( { SSL_fingerprint => $fp } );
```

Neither way UA (LWP) seems not get set properly. How to achieve the `SSL_fingerprint` setting? I need it because site's certificate has some chain flaw in and without specifying the fingerprint I can't connect it securely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set SSL options, you need to pass 2 arguments to the [`ssl_opts`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ssl_opts) method of `LWP::UserAgent`: the name of the option and its value. Thus, you should do:

```
$pic->ua->ssl_opts( SSL_fingerprint => $fp );
```

In your code, you are passing a hash reference to `ssl_opts` (`{ SSL_fingerprint => $fp }`). When a single argument is passed to `ssl_opts`, this argument is expected to be the name of an option, and the function
returns the value associated to this name.

Answer (score 2):

Your code `$pic->ua` will return the UA object that is being used inside the Image::Grab object. So calling methods on that should do the right thing.

Having said that, [the documentation for `ssl_opts()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ssl_opts) contains these examples:

> ```
> my @keys = $ua->ssl_opts;
> my $val = $ua->ssl_opts( $key );
> $ua->ssl_opts( $key => $value );
> ```

So it looks like you need to remove the anonymous hash constructor from your code:

```
$pic->ua->ssl_opts( SSL_fingerprint => $fp );
```

Alternatively, you could try creating your own UA object:

```
my $ua = Image::Grab::RequestAgent->new(...);
```

And then inserting that into the Image::Grab object:

```
$pic->ua($ua);
```

Image::Grab::RequestAgent is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent and therefore its constructor will accept all of the same arguments.